# How to use JSP tags in JSP fragment?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude, jsp-fragments

Can anyone tell me if you can use JSP tags like this:

```
<c:if test="true" > ... </c:if>
```

in fragments of JSPs with a .jspf extension which are embedded into JSPs using include, e.g.:

```
<jsp:include page = "/WEB-INF/jspf/about/banner.jspf" />
```

or is it better to use fragments of code with a .jsp extension embedded in parent JSPs?

Answer (score 0):

**Using .jspf extension** allows the container to not require evaluation of the page-code from within HTML /HTML tag pairs as would be with .jsp.
Any .jspf must be **kept in /WEB-INF/jspf directory** to assist telling the container **it is not loading a completed markup page**.
(only a note:)A simpler method of including running partial markup code is an implicit loaded .tag file that is kept in /WEB-INF/tags (not the same as compiled class files but is called into the page the same way with a name space declaration and its tag name).

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the "c"-library (I guess it's the JSTL core library) in your .jspf file as you do it in a .jsp file, and then use it:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

...

<c:if test="true" > ... </c:if>
```